# Increase radius on heat map for Maps API on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, heatmap

I've created an heat map on Google Maps API for Android. The problem is when I increase zoom, the heat map "looses" radius and the look is not that good.

There`s a way to increase radius above 50 (Probably the maximum)? :/

[image: Heat map with less zoom]

[image: Heat map on zoom]

Comment: . how did you solve this problem?  I have the same issue. . !

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/heatmap):

> Radius: The size of the Gaussian blur applied to the heatmap,
>   expressed in pixels. The default is 20. Must be between 10 and 50. Use
>   the Builder's radius() to set the value when creating the heatmap, or
>   change the value later with setRadius().

So, if you use the `radius(int val)` function from the `HeatmapTileProvider.Builder` you will receive an `IllegalArgumentException("Radius not within bounds.")` exception if the radius is not between 10 an 50.

Taking a look at [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/heatmaps/HeatmapTileProvider.java) you can see that the `radius(int val)` function checks if the parameter is between `MIN_RADIUS` and `MAX_RADIUS`.

Anyway there is a `setRadius(int radius)` function on the `HeatmapTileProvider` class that you can use (take a look at he implementation in [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/heatmaps/HeatmapTileProvider.java)).

So, as the `setRadius(int radius)` function does not check the parameter, you can change the radius of the `HeatmapTileProvider` after calling `build()` as follows:

```
HeatmapTileProvider mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
        .data(list)
        .build();
mProvider.setRadius(100);
```

Using the police stations example, and setting the radius to 50:

[image: Setting the radius to 50]

And setting the radius to 100:

[image: Setting the radius to 100]

You may want to dynamically change the radius of the HeatMap based on the zoom level.

**NOTE:** Take into account that, as stated in the Javadoc for the `setRadius` function:

> User should clear overlay's tile cache (using `clearTileCache()`) after
>   calling this.