# Heatmap Overlay with weighted sum of latlng?

Tags: android, google-maps, heatmap

How to apply heatmap overlay in android with specific colors for specific values. so that the weighted sum appears to be same as the individual heatmap spot?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Are you currently generating heatmaps and you need to change it's color?

Comment: Yes iam generating heatmaps from google api, using set gradient method i can change the gradient color alone. but when i use the weighted latlng with a specific intensity for each latlng it appears good.But when i zoom out the map the colors merge and appears a red at center.But what i want is for each latlng a specific color should defined so that when i zoom out that color will merge on another. so the color for certain latlng will be same when i zoom out. thanks i advance

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257612/increase-radius-on-heat-map-for-maps-api-on-android/35258354#35258354 You will need to calculate the radius based on the zoom level

Answer (score 0):

**How to apply heatmap overlay in android with specific colors for specific values**

In the [Android Heatmap docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/heatmap#introduction), you can set your own colors for heatmap using setGradient();

Here's a sample of [Customizing HeatMaps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/heatmap#custom):

```
// Create the gradient.
int[] colors = {
    Color.rgb(102, 225, 0), // green
    Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)    // red
};

float[] startPoints = {
    0.2f, 1f
};

Gradient gradient = new Gradient(colors, startPoints);

// Create the tile provider.
mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
     .data(mList)
     .gradient(gradient)
     .build();

// Add the tile overlay to the map.
mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
```